# Does ozone has dipole forces

Tags: intermolecular-forces

Considering ozone in liquid state, certainly there are london forces, but does the position of its molecules induce dipole intermolecular forces?

Comment: "London forces" _are_ dipole-dipole forces. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon I was thinking about dispersion forces.

Comment: Ah. Dipole-dipole forces are dispersion forces. At least, when one induced dipole causes another induced dipole. If this happens, then dispersion is present.

Answer (score 2):

Ozone has a bent structure with a partial positive charge on the central oxygen atom and partial negative charges on the two terminal oxygens. It has a permanent dipole moment of 0.53 D, according to Wikipedia.